# How to reduce the space on disk used by a string having only a limited set of characters?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have text files on disk, which use only the following characters:

```
Numbers: 0-9
Comma: ,
Pipe symbol: |
Colon: :
Semi-Colon: ;
Asterisk: *
Exclamation: !
```

So my file content may look like:

> 21:1,0|16:1,0|20:1,0|8:1,-1|3:1,3|14:2,-1;1,0|2:0,0|1:1,0|0:1,74!3:1,5|2:11,7|1:1,1|0:1,138

Is there a way I can encode these files to reduce their size on disk ?
Right now I store them as text files, which are easy for humans to read, but in future space would be more important.

**What is a quick and easy way to encode and decode the files (to reduce their size), since I know that I am using only these characters?**

I would like to use only STL (no boost etc).

Comment: since there are 16 symbols, you could pack them 2 to a byte. or just use zlib.

Comment: @dgsomerton Can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: What your data *means* is more important than the characters used. We have no idea what all those characters mean in your application. We also don't know what range of numbers are accepted in your data format. While simple text compression would work, you may be able to get better compression by actually knowing something about the data you are storing.

Comment: By keeping your order, something like `21:1,0|16:1,` -> 0x21 0xC1 0xA0 0xB1 0x6C 0x1A. you would have to have flag or size to handle final possible incomplete byte.

Comment: @GregHewgill - There are several unused characters in my file - for example, I don't use any letters, or the following special characters (@,#,$ etc - only the characters mentioned above). I imagine there should be some way of expressing this file in a different format than an ascii text file, and saving space, just knowing the information mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, sure, if you don't care to know actually what the data means, then Huffman coding is about the best you can do.

Comment: If there are many long runs of identical characters then a simple run length encoding could give good results. Otherwise Huffman coding is also pretty simple.

Comment: This looks like a rather broad question. If the files are representation of structured data, knowing the structure will help to find an efficient algorythm. Then, depending whether you need a direct access to a specific record, a generic compression could be or not a good choice.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - the structure isn't fixed. What I'm looking for is something simple like Marco Pantaleoni's answer below, where I'm just stuffing the information into ints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient compression would be obtained by using a data compression library. A very efficient one for example is [lz4](https://lz4.github.io/lz4/). Other alternatives are [FastLZ](http://fastlz.org), [Zstandard](https://github.com/facebook/zstd), [QuickLZ](http://www.quicklz.com), [zlib](https://www.zlib.net), ...

But if you want to avoid external dependencies, in your case you can start from the consideration that you have only 16 different characters. You can map those characters to the integers in range 0-15 (for example, using an array of integers indexed by character, or a `std::map`). A number in range 0-15 can be represented using 4 bits, so a byte can store two of those integers, thus halving your storage space, in a very simple manner. You only have to take care of edge cases when you have only one character in the last byte.

A very rough code sample:

```
uint8_t char_map[128];
std::string packed_string;

...
// initialize char_map[]
char_map['0'] = 0;
char_map['1'] = 1;
...
char_map['!'] = 15;
...


char ch1 = mystring[i];
char ch2 = mystring[i + 1];
uint8_t idx1 = char_map[static_cast<int>(ch1)];  // integer range 0-15 representing ch1 - char at pos i
uint8_t idx2 = char_map[static_cast<int>(ch2)];  // integer range 0-15 representing ch2 - char at pos i+1
uint8_t packed = idx1 | (idx2 << 4);             // stuff both in a single 8-bit integer (equivalent to a char)

// append the packed character to the "compressed" string
packed_string.push_back(static_cast<char>(packed)); // or packed_string[dst++] = static_cast<char>(packed) if using an C string
i += 2;                                          // advance by 2 (we processed two characters) in the source string
...
```

Note that if you are processing very large files, larger than memory, you'll probably want to avoid creating the whole compressed string in one go, but maybe write directly to the output file, or proceed in chunks.

To unpack you'll need to to the reverse operation, using another map int -> char and doing masking and shifting to extract the integers:

```
...
uint8_t idx1 = packed & 0x0F;
uint8_t idx2 = (packed & 0xF0) >> 4;
char ch1 = map_int2char[idx1];
char ch2 = map_int2char[idx2];
...
```

Comment: Hmm it sounds like a good idea - but i don't understand some of your code. You're converting each characters representation to an uint8_t, but what are you doing in this line: packer = idx1 | (idx2 <<4);  Also, what is packed_string ?

Comment: `idx1` is the integer in range 0-15 for `ch1`, `idx2` for `ch2`, with `packed = idx1 | (idx2 << 4)` I'm stuffing an 8-bit integer with both integers `idx1` and `idx2`, putting `idx1` in the lower 4 bits and `idx2` in the higher 4 bits. So you have two characters in a single 8 bit integer, which occupies a single character. `packed_string` is the compressed string. This is only "pseudo-code" btw, just to give you an idea and a starting point.

Comment: That sounds like using this method, I would reduce the size of my original string by 50% is that correct? Also, by packed_string[dst++] are you referring to the character at the index dst?

Comment: yes, 50%. `packed_string[dst++] = ...` assigns to the destination string at position `dst` and then increments `dst` by one (post-increment operator). If you are more comfortable with std::string you can use that too instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of compressing text files, one of the easiest ones is the [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

In it you would map different symbols according to their occurrence in the current file to a binary code. You could calculate the occurrences once and save this compression table hard coded in your program or you save the table in each file. This choice depends on the size of your files. If they are pretty big adding this table would not make a big difference.